# Recursive query in MySQL 8.0 with dynamic table names

Tags: mysql, window-functions, mysql-8.0

I have two tables, one is `sections`, this has an `id`, a `parent_table` and a `parent_id`, the other is `pages` which has a `id` and `status` (and other) columns. The parent of a section can be another section or a page, with according `parent_table` values. How could I find out using window functions whether a given section is on a `status = 1` page or not? (using MySQL 8.0 (or MariaDB 10.2) but in a pinch I could convert into postgresql if badly necessary).

Example data:

## sections

```
id|parent_table|parent_id
1 |pages       |1
2 |sections    |1
3 |pages       |2
4 |sections    |2
```

## pages

```
id|status
 1|1
 2|0
```

To recreate the sample data:

```
create table pages (id int not null primary key, status int not null) collate utf8mb4_general_ci;
create table sections (id int not null primary key, parent_table varchar(20), parent_id int not null) collate utf8mb4_general_ci;
insert into pages values (1,1),(2,0);
insert into sections values (1,'pages',1),(2,'sections',1),(3,'pages',2),(4,'sections',2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the corresponding page status for all sections, you can use the following recursive query:

```
with recursive r as (
  select s.id as section_id, s.parent_id, s.parent_table
  from sections s
  union all
  select r.section_id, s.parent_id, s.parent_table
  from r
  join sections s on s.id = r.parent_id and r.parent_table = 'sections'
)
select r.section_id, p.id as page_id, p.status
from r
join pages p on p.id = r.parent_id
where r.parent_table = 'pages';
```

Result:

```
| section_id | page_id | status |
| ---------- | ------- | ------ |
| 1          | 1       | 1      |
| 2          | 1       | 1      |
| 4          | 1       | 1      |
| 3          | 2       | 0      |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vL43JtXUmyGSCLbNj2igjw/0)

The recursion traverses the tree from any section to its root section. This way you can limit the result to a single section in the inner query. Eg. if you only want to know the status of section 3, you would use a WHERE clause in the first UNION part of the RCTE:

```
with recursive r as (
  select s.id as section_id, s.parent_id, s.parent_table
  from sections s
  where s.id = 3 -- limit to a single section
  union all
  select r.section_id, s.parent_id, s.parent_table
  from r
  join sections s on s.id = r.parent_id and r.parent_table = 'sections'
)
select r.section_id, p.id as page_id, p.status
from r
join pages p on p.id = r.parent_id
where r.parent_table = 'pages';
```

Result:

```
| section_id | page_id | status |
| ---------- | ------- | ------ |
| 3          | 2       | 0      |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ik2pNUobpeZEiEKvzKwiNN/0)

Answer (score 0):

Without Windows Function the SQL query will be like this

SQL Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM sections WHERE parent_table = 'pages'  and parent_id IN
(SELECT id FROM pages WHERE pages.status= 1)
```

With Windows Function the code will be like below:

```
declare @parent_table varchar(5)
declare @status int
set @status=1;
set @parent_table='pages';
with pages as (
/* Anchor member */
select s.id, s.parent_table, s.parent_id 
from sections s
where s.parent_table=@parent_table
UNION ALL
/* Recursive Member */
select s.id, s.parent_table, s.parent_id, 
from sections s
join pages on
    s.parent_table=@parent_table and s.parent_id=pages.id)
select status from pages where status=1
option(MAXRECURSION 500)
```

We can set MAXRECURSION between 1 and 32767

Comment: This is SQL Server code, I removed the DECLARE and the option and it still gave me `Unknown column 'Level' in 'field list'`.

Comment: Yeah! thought of previous queries and added level, the level is a field which does not exist hence not required. Yes, we can remove declare but it works well when you decide to convert this query into a function or procedure.  Reusability is the thing we cannot miss it.